# Not able to analysis loadrunner result

Tags: automation, load, loadrunner

I am new to loadrunner, using loadrunner 9.1.
I can create script, scenario but not able to analysis result (graph).
Is there any way to analysis graph?
how can we determine impact of load on application by using graph?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

"how can we determine impact of load on application by using graph?"

What you ask is simple, but the answer not so.  To answer you would take volumes, with large depedencies upoin your application architecture.

As you are new to LoadRunner may we ask
* Have you been through training?
* Are you involved in an internship program for your first several projects?

James Pulley

Moderator

-SQAForums WinRunner, LoadRunner

-YahooGroups LoadRunner, Advanced LoadRunner

-GoogleGroups lr-loadrunner

-LinkedIn LoadRunner (owner), LoadRunnerByTheHour (Owner)

Mercury Alum (1996-2000)

CTO, Newcoe Performance Engineering | LoadRunnerByTheHour.com

Comment: i haven't attend any training..i got functionality by self..but now i struck by graph analysis..

Comment: I recommend the following references

Comment: Apologies for the abbreviated one above....I exceeded the five minute mark on my edits.  I recommend the following references, "Modern Operating Systems" & "Distributed Systems: Principles and Paradigms" by Andrew Tanenbaum, Your choice of books on the relational database model by Mssrs E.F.Codd & C.J.Date, "High Performance TCP/IP Networking" by Hassan & Jain, "Chaos, making a new science" by James Gleick. This should get you started.